# Do I have to restart my machine for ulimit - u to take affect?

Tags: linux, ulimit

So I have an external 3rd party application which runs on Java. The JVM is getting a load of `OutOfMemeory` errors and their support team suggested I raise the `ulimit - u` from he default `1024` to `4096`

There is a start-up shell script that starts the server. This essentially sets some environment variables and executes the Java. I've added the following line:

`ulimit -u 4096`

How will I know this has worked? Do I need to start my machine to get this to come into affect?

Answer (score 0):

ulimit only raises the possible file descriptors per application, but you dont seem to have a problem with descriptors but with memory, how do you start this java-based tool?

Anyway for this to work you have to increase your heap allocation space. The parameter -Xms for the java command sets the initial size of the heap. Check the link at the bottom for further details [1] Just increase the size.

Regards

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#nonstandard

Comment: I gave their support team the logs and that is what they suggested based on the logs. Heapspace is set to 6GB as per their recommendation.

Comment: If it was about the file descriptors then you'd have this error here: https://customer.stone-ware.com/support/techdocs/kb/s2548/Too%20Many%20Open%20Files%20Pattern.htm